# Games run better when I'm not charging

Tags: laptop, performance, battery, charging

I couldn't find any answear/solution for my problem, which is when I play a game like GTA 5, GTA 4 or basically any other, I get worse FPS (Like 30fps less) when I keep my laptop charging.

On the other side, when I unplug the laptop I instantly gain 60fps and run smoothly, I have set maximal performance mode in both cases - pluged or unplugged and still have the same problem.

I want to point out, that I dont have to restart the game or do anything while unplugging the cord and getting higher fps, hope you get what I want to say. (i5 3210M, AMD Radeon HD and 8GB ram).

So the question is: How can I make the laptop perform the same while plugged as while unplugged?

Comment: This sounds like thermal throttling. Have you got any stats on your system temperatures? Have you tried removing the dust for the vents and the fans?

Comment: Well, the laptop is 2012, I attempted to clear the dust as much as I could, as well I reapplied the thermal paste, but I have experienced this issue even before all of that

Comment: My theory is that the PSU/battery is chucking out more heat when charging than the system can handle and that is why it is throttling you in games. However without any temperature data to back this up your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @IDKMN When this occurs, does your CPU also drop to a lower clock speed?

Comment: @JW0914 By the info that afterburner gave me, there is just little 1 watt change for cpu, but I dont know what those watts displayed mean so. Actually, the only difference is, that the game is instantly way more smooth when unplugged + more fps

Comment: @IDKMN Isn't afterburner for GPUs, or does it also show CPU clock speed in realtime?  When your issue occurs with the laptop plugged in, does your CPU clock speed drop to ~0.7 -0.9GHz?

Answer (score 0):

1. In windows, go to the "power sleep settings" and select "Power Options". Select "High Performance" when your plugged in your charger. Go and customize the advanced options and select everything with maximum performance.
2. Use tools like "AVG PC Tune Up" or "Game Booster" to kill background processes.

This worked for me!

Hope it Helps!

Happy Gaming!

Comment: Hi, I tried putting everything to maximize, but it didnt work, but I dont know what happened recently, my screen went black for maybe second and now the performance is waaay better, but still not as off charger